# Topnav, float: right but want the link on the left

Tags: html, css

Hello people I'ts my first question on here so I'm sorry breaking any rules, or creating a silly topic. I am starting my journey with HTML and CSS, and I have to re-create a site from the picture. It contains a simple site template with a navigation bar above the main header. I am trying to fit the topnav above it, and make the links appear on the right side, but in the right order: Home->About Us->...->Contact. 
Float:right declaration helped me set the navigation on top of the site, but the link appear only on the left side. How can I move them to the left without ruining the order? Here's my HTML and CSS code.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    background-color: #b1b1b1;
    direction: rtl;
}

li {
    float: right;
    direction: rtl;
}

.topnav {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        direction: rtl;
    }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en-US">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li><em><a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#aboutus" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#services" style="text-decoration:none">Services</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#solutions" style="text-decoration:none">Solutions</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#support" style="text-decoration:none">Support</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#partners" style="text-decoration:none">Partners</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#contact" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></em></li>
     </ul>
</div>
 
 
  <header>

   <h1>Welcome</h1>
   <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h2>

  </header>
```

As I said, i'ts my first task to do in HTML and CSS, so my code is messy. Feel free to ask any questions! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple just `remove float` from the li and give it `display:inline-block;` and add `text-align: right` to `ul`  see code below:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    background-color: #b1b1b1;
    text-align:right;
}

li {
   display: inline-block;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        direction: rtl;
    }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en-US">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li><em><a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#aboutus" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#services" style="text-decoration:none">Services</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#solutions" style="text-decoration:none">Solutions</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#support" style="text-decoration:none">Support</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#partners" style="text-decoration:none">Partners</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#contact" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></em></li>
     </ul>
</div>
 
 
  <header>

   <h1>Welcome</h1>
   <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h2>

  </header>
```

Comment: Strange, I've changed it, and it didn't work. I've literally copypasted your answer and still nothing :/

Comment: Is there any other CSS you included which override this CSS ?

Comment: Nothing that would concern the top navigation and header.
Rest of the code:

h1 {
  color: #5796f5
}

.grid {
 display: grid;
 height: 300px;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-row-gap: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  padding: 30px;
  }
  
  .description {
   font-size: 20px;
  }

.ostatnie {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 66% 33%;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    padding: 40px;
}
  
(No footer)

Comment: any other changes you noticed which are different in the snippet ? in HTML?

Comment: remove `.topnav { direction: rtl; text-align: right;}`  from css

Comment: Yes! Finally it worked! I've removed .topnav and switched back to your answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you apply `float: right` to each item in your list which causes a backward list. 
 
Simply move your `float` to its parent `ul` and move the style of the `ul` to its parent container `.topnav`.
Prevent the `width: 100%` by setting `display: inline-block` to `ul` and `li`s. 
 
You can also remove the `float: right` by a `text-align: right; display: block` : your `ul` will be 100% wide and its children will align to the right.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.topnav {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    background-color: #b1b1b1;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        direction: rtl;
    }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en-US">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li><em><a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#aboutus" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#services" style="text-decoration:none">Services</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#solutions" style="text-decoration:none">Solutions</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#support" style="text-decoration:none">Support</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#partners" style="text-decoration:none">Partners</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#contact" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></em></li>
     </ul>
</div>
 
 
  <header>

   <h1>Welcome</h1>
   <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h2>

  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `float:left` in li

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    background-color: #b1b1b1;
    direction: rtl;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

.topnav {
    text-align: right;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en-US">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li><em><a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#aboutus" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#services" style="text-decoration:none">Services</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#solutions" style="text-decoration:none">Solutions</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#support" style="text-decoration:none">Support</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#partners" style="text-decoration:none">Partners</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#contact" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></em></li>
     </ul>
</div>
 
 
  <header>

   <h1>Welcome</h1>
   <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h2>

  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

add css below:

```
ul {
width: 100%;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #b1b1b1;
text-align: right;
}
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
/* remove float and direction properties */
}
```

if you don't get menu in one line decrease padding form `<a>` tag